# Angular Form Arrays remove required if one field is filled

Tags: angular, typescript

I am struggling with form arrays required validation,I have to remove validations from the form arrays if one of the given field is filled.

here is my code

.ts

```
    this.form = fb.group({
    contract: this.fb.array([], this.AtLeastOneFieldValidator)
    )};
  ifContractEmpty() {
    const eArray = this.contractArray.value;
    const length = this.contractArray.length;
    if (length > 1) {
      if (
        eArray[length - 1].salesOrderNumber == null &&
        eArray[length - 1].customerPOnumber == null &&
        eArray[length - 1].contractNumber == null
      ) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  AtLeastOneFieldValidator(group: FormGroup): { [key: string]: any } {
    let isAtLeastOne = false;
    if (group && group.controls) {
      for (const control in group.controls) {
        if (
          group.controls.hasOwnProperty(control) &&
          group.controls[control].valid &&
          group.controls[control].value
        ) {
          isAtLeastOne = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return isAtLeastOne ? null : { required: true };
  }

 addContactGroup() {
    return this.fb.group({
      salesOrderNumber: "",
      customerPOnumber: "",
      contractNumber: ""
    });
  }

  addContract() {
    this.contractArray.push(this.addContactGroup());
  }
 get contractArray() {
    return <FormArray>this.rForm.get("contract");
  }
```

I have set required attribute on the html but if I am not sure if I should or not. my only thing is from those three if one is filled then others two should not required.

I have tried to use custom Validator as you can see from above but that did not help

Comment: "I have set required attribute on the html but if I am not sure if I should or not." You should not. And validator should return true/false.

Comment: you have to create custom validation then see **setErrors()** method in angular.

Comment: @BharatChauhan right but I am using button [disabled]="!form.valid" and even my all of those values are empty the form because valid

Comment: and if use required attribute in all three in input field then it keeps invalid unless i fill all of them